# Why isn't my hamburger menu sticked when I'm scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying the responsivness of my website and I can see that my hamburger menu isn't sticked when I'm scrolling.
The other problem I have with it is that when I click on it the background comes on it and it hides my hamburger so I can't click it back. Already tried z-index but It doesn't work.

I don't understand what's the problem here.

Any ideas?

here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/MWPgbyw

Thanks for your help

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.menu a').forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('menu-toggle').checked = false;
    });
});
```

```css
body{
  background: pink;
}

.label-toggle {
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}


.menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    transition: right 0.4s ease;
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.menu ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: hagincaps;
    font-size: 28px;
}


#menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu {
    right: 0;
}


.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}



input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 747px) {
    .navbar{
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 748px) {
    .label-toggle,
    .menu {
        display: none;
    }

    .content {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-toggle">
        <label for="menu-toggle" class="label-toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#5">5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-container">
                <a href="#">1</a>
                <a href="#2">2</a>
                <a href="#3">3</a>
                <a href="#4">4</a>
                <a href="#5">5</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

        <section id="avis">
        <header>
            <h1>Avis</h1>
        </header>

        <div class="Slider">
    <input checked="checked" class="points" name="avis_slider" title="slide1" type="radio"> <input class="points" name="avis_slider" title="slide2" type="radio"> <input class="points" name="avis_slider" title="slide3" type="radio"> <input class="points" name="avis_slider" title="slide4" type="radio"> <input class="points" name="avis_slider" title="slide5" type="radio">

    <div class="avisSlider">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="etoiles">
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="far fa-star fa-2x"></i>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita corrupti, odit in. Vero perferendis hic molestias nisi, labore adipisci dolores, iusto architecto dolorem soluta totam aperiam corporis minus esse tempore!</p>

        <h2>Publié par Antoine</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="etoiles">
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita corrupti, odit in. Vero perferendis hic molestias nisi, labore adipisci dolores, iusto architecto dolorem soluta totam aperiam corporis minus esse tempore!</p>
        
        <h2>Publié par José</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="etoiles">
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="far fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="far fa-star fa-2x"></i>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita corrupti, odit in. Vero perferendis hic molestias nisi, labore adipisci dolores, iusto architecto dolorem soluta totam aperiam corporis minus esse tempore!</p>
        
        <h2>Publié par Corentin</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="etoiles">
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita corrupti, odit in. Vero perferendis hic molestias nisi, labore adipisci dolores, iusto architecto dolorem soluta totam aperiam corporis minus esse tempore!</p>
        
        <h2>Publié par Rose</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="etoiles">
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="far fa-star fa-2x"></i>
          <i class="far fa-star fa-2x"></i>
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita corrupti, odit in. Vero perferendis hic molestias nisi, labore adipisci dolores, iusto architecto dolorem soluta totam aperiam corporis minus esse tempore!</p>
        
        <h2>Publié par Sofia</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty simple solution, if you want your hamburger menu to stick when you're scrolling you need to have a `position: sticky` CSS property with a `top: 0`.

[image: .label-toggle CSS with both properties needed]

Then your menu will follow the page when it's being scrolled.
But I couldn't figure out the problem you were having with the background, I clicked the background and it didn't hide

Could you try explaining it again or maybe send a screenshot

Comment: Hey thanks ! It's working. 
For the other problem, in my codepen if you try responsive, the hamburger will appear. If you click on the hamburger, you'll see the background will hide the hamburger icon.

Comment: Any news ? Did you find anything?

Comment: Oh I see, if you add the position and top changes that I've mentioned above, all you've got to do now is to add z-index to with a higher value, maybe it wasn't working before because there was no position specified